# How do I near the inputs I make on my phone towards my server via command

Tags: linux, session, ssh, terminal, progress

I'm trying to mirror my terminals screen on my phone but it's Ubuntu servers TL I want to mirror so when I go out and about I can do some typing on my phone and then when I get home I can resume from where I left off without having to go through the whole entire process I set up again like for example I'm at home using my terminal right and I left off from saying that my text hi and goodbye need to continue and then I'm out and about like at the shopping market or something I open I pull up my phone and I go to juice SSH and I connect via there and it will reconnect me to my current session I already have open and then when I get home it will let me go off when I left off I hope you understand this stack overflow don't fail me :D

I tried going on the internet trying to figure this out because I had no idea where to start for coding which I know some and I tried the internet but I couldn't find anything so I'm trying to overflow I use their services a lot very helpful and hopefully they can help me with my question this is the first time so please don't fail me

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `screen`

```
$ sudo apt install screen
$ screen -S mysessionname
# run commands
```

To detach from it: CTRL+a+d

To attach from your SSH client in your phone:

```
$ screen -r
```

To detach the session at your phone, since keyboard shortcuts are not available, you would need to detach it from your server terminal:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        8365.pts-6.vm2    (Attached)
        7317.pts-1.vm2    (Attached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.

$ screen -d 8365
[8365.pts-6.vm2 detached.]
```